# Including constants without importing header file

Tags: c++, global, shared-memory

I have a piece of code set up to take a constant integer parameter (dimension of the problem), but it could run with many different dimensions.

I don't want to have to change the hard-coded dimension every time I run, I would ideally define several dummy header functions that are basically just:

```
#ifndef dim_define_h 
#define dim_define_h 

    const int dimension = [DIMENSION SPECIFIC TO THIS HEADER FILE];

#endif
```

Then when compiling I could use whichever header file I needed for that instance like:

```
g++ dimension_6.h code.cpp
```

Is such a thing possible? Defining a constant in a header file and using it in another file that doesn't explicitly import that header file?

---

EDIT:

My next attempt was to take the main function only, stick it along with the dimension definition in a different file, and make copies of that. Then the compilation looks like:

```
g++ dim_specific_main.cpp lots.cpp more.cpp helpers.cpp
```

And I think it's making it through the compilation of main now, which depend on helper functions defined in all the helper files. Unfortunately when it tries to compile the helper functions it needs the constant that's defined in main.h and it seems to have forgotten it.

EDIT 2: I realize now that I'm trying to use this variable in places where it needs to be known at compile time, and I think that the linkage happens after compiling, so I do not believe this particular approach is possible.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__DIM_DEFINE_H__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: "I don't want to have to change the hard-coded dimension every time I run" So don't hard code it.

Comment: Making the code dimension agnostic is an unacceptable increase in run-time unfortunately. Otherwise I'd be with you, I know that globals and hard-coded constants are bad form.

Comment: What evidence do you have  thinking making the dimensions non-hard coded would cause performance problems?

Comment: Implementation, unfortunately. This code has a pretty small time window it has to fit into. I bet there are other places that I can optimize, but this is the one I'm working on today.

Comment: @PeteBecker I fixed that privileged variable name, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const int dimension = THE_DIMENSION;
```

then compile with

```
g++ -DTHE_DIMENSION=6 code.cpp
```

No header needed.

Comment: This works in general, unfortunately I'm in a pretty rigid environment and I can't even really add more flags to the automated system's compiling method.

Comment: @Emichael can you build the header file from a template prior to compilation?

Comment: I'm not sure what's involved in that, can you point me to any examples?

Comment: use a makefile rule to produce the header file from a template file. you could use a tool like `sed` to do the transformation.